# Navigation Menu Not Working on Big Cartel

Tags: javascript, html, css, bigcartel

I have a custom drop-down navigation menu that I want to use on my big cartel theme. It has HTML, CSS and Java Script.

Unfortunately, It is not working. The Java Script helps with the toggle event.
The drop-downs are on "Shop" and "About". When I click those dropdowns, they don't show.

In my Big Cartel Theme, I first tried linking to the JS file    -- that didn't work.
I then put the script in the   area and it still didn't work.

Here's the code working
https://codepen.io/findingcolors/pen/ZErZZgo

**HTML**

```
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-mobile"><a id="nav-toggle" href="#!"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i> &nbsp; Menu</a></div>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Shop &nbsp; <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="https://www.maddiemarieexclusives.com/products">All Products</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="https://www.maddiemarieexclusives.com/category/sticker">Stickers</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="https://www.maddiemarieexclusives.com/category/notes">Notepads + Sticky Notes</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="https://www.maddiemarieexclusives.com/category/bookmark">Bookmarks</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="https://www.maddiemarieexclusives.com/category/jewelry">Jewelry</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="https://www.maddiemarieexclusives.com/category/phone-strap">Phone Straps</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">About &nbsp; <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="https://www.maddiemarieexclusives.com/the-brand">The Brand</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="https://www.maddiemarieexclusives.com/shipping-returns">Shipping + Returns</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="https://www.maddiemarieexclusives.com/faq">FAQ</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Cart</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Search</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* --- NAVIGATION bar --- */
 .navigation {
     height: 50px;
     background: #fefcfc;
     font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
 .nav-container {
     text-align: center;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
 nav {
     font-size: 16px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: bold;
}
 nav ul {
     list-style: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
 nav ul li {
     float: left;
     position: relative;
}
 nav ul li a, nav ul li a:visited {
     display: block;
     padding: 0 20px;
     line-height: 50px;
     background: #fefcfc;
     color: #716558;
     text-decoration: none;
}
 nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a:visited:hover {
     color: #90867a;
}
 nav ul li ul li {
     min-width: 250px;
}
 nav ul li ul li a {
     padding: 15px;
     line-height: 20px;
}
 .nav-dropdown {
     position: absolute;
     display: none;
     z-index: 1;
     text-align: left;
}
/* Mobile navigation */
 .nav-mobile {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     background: #fefcfc;
     height: 50px;
     width: 50px;
}
 @media only screen and (max-width: 798px) {
     .nav-mobile {
         display: block;
    }
     nav {
         width: 100%;
         padding: 50px 0 15px;
    }
     nav ul {
         display: none;
         text-align: left;
    }
     nav ul li {
         float: none;
    }
     nav ul li a {
         padding: 15px;
         line-height: 20px;
    }
     nav ul li ul li a {
         padding-left: 30px;
    }
     .nav-dropdown {
         position: static;
    }
}
 @media screen and (min-width: 799px) {
     .nav-list {
         display: inline-block;
    }
}
 #nav-toggle {
     position: absolute;
     left: -160px;
     top: 10px;
     cursor: pointer;
     padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
     color: #716558;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 16px;
}
 article {
     max-width: 1000px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 10px;
}
```

**Java**

```
(function($) { // Begin jQuery
  $(function() { // DOM ready
    // If a link has a dropdown, add sub menu toggle.
    $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
      $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();
      // Close one dropdown when selecting another
      $('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
    // Clicking away from dropdown will remove the dropdown class
    $('html').click(function() {
      $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
    });
    // Toggle open and close nav styles on click
    $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
      $('nav ul').slideToggle();
    });
    // Hamburger to X toggle
    $('#nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
      this.classList.toggle('active');
    });
  }); // end DOM ready
})(jQuery); // end jQuery
```

Comment: Your *dropdowns* show up just fine in the Windows Firefox and Chrome/Edge codepen. In both desktop and mobile layout.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery library was missing from the website.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

After including it, the navigation menu is working now.

Comment: ```<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>```